# Como pintar una gráfica con matplolib a partir de un dataframe de Pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, matplotlib

Ante todo he de decir que no tengo muchos conocimientos de programación porque llevo sólo 1 mes con ello.
Tengo un dataframe obtenido a partir de un excel *xls en el que un campo "Barrio" refleja los barrios de Madrid y además tengo datos de densidades de población por año para cada barrio. (Dens_año)

Pongo por aquí el código con el que he obtenido el df a patir del excel original.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#CamposDens = ["Dens_2008","Dens_2009","Dens_2010","Dens_2011","Dens_2012","Dens_2013","Dens_2014","Dens_2015","Dens_2016","Dens_2017","Dens_2018"]
def DfTranXLS (excel):
    datos = pd.read_excel(excel)
    df=pd.DataFrame(datos)
    df = df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]], axis=1)
    return df
print DfTranXLS(r"C:\Users\Esteban\Desktop\Trabajo Python actualizado\H_Poblacion.xls")
```

Necesito que alguien me explique cómo puedo pintar una gráfica que refleje la evolución de densidad para cada barrio con los años, sé que lo más fácil es definir una función con un parámetro barrio con el que llamar después a la función, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Gracias!

### Edición 1

Añado enlace al excel original

https://www101.zippyshare.com/v/A6OwPfTU/file.html

### Edición 2

gracias por tu explicación, y siento no haber comentado antes que trabajo en IDLE, pero mis limitados conocimientos hacen que no entienda muy bien la implicación de trabajar en un entorno u otro, aunque según me contó un amigo informático IDLE en el mundillo es de lo más rudimentario que hay ahora mismo. En fin estoy intentando escribir el código para que pinte la gráfica pero no me sale:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def grafica(data, Barrio):

    info_barrios = data.loc[data['Barrio'] == Barrio]
    info_barrios = info_barrios.drop(info_barrios.columns[[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]], axis=1)
    info_barrios = info_barrios.set_index("Barrio").T     # La T es de "Transpose", cambia filas por columnas
    info_barrios.index=list(range(2008, 2019))  # Reasignar el índice para que sea numérico
    print info_barrios
    return info_barrios

Barrios_data = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\Esteban\Desktop\Trabajo Python 
actualizado\H_Poblacion.xls")

print ("Llamada Moncloa")
Moncloa_grafica = grafica(Barrios_data,"MONCLOA")
plt.plot(Moncloa_grafica)
plt.show()
```

El error que sale es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Esteban\Desktop\Trabajo Python actualizado\grafica4.py", line 17, in <module>
    plt.plot(Moncloa_grafica)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3153, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1382, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 381, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 369, in _plot_args
    seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

No entiendo de dónde saca el error de división por cero, si se supone que estoy pintando una gráfica... siento que estoy cerca, si me puedes ayudar t lo agradezco

Comment: No se ve apenas el texto en la imagen que has copiado, pero si es como me parece, quizás algo tan simple como esto sea suficiente: `df.set_index("Barrio").T.plot()`. Si no, sería conveniente que subieras a algún sitio tu excel (o parte de ella) y pusieras un enlace, para que pudiéramos hacer pruebas con tus datos.

Comment: Si, perdona, soy nuevo en la página, ahora subo el excel original.

Comment: Respecto al código que pones en la edicion 2, creo que el problema está en la forma en que seleccionas el barrio, que seguramente causa un dataframe vacío que después no se puede pintar (porque seguramente pandas en algún momento divide entre un número que resulta ser cero por no haber datos). ¿Por qué no lo haces como yo lo hice? Es decir, primero acondicionar el datagrama completo, y después seleccionar sobre ese datagrama un subset de columnas. En tu caso el subset sería `["MONCLOA"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De mano necesitas cambiar la organización del dataframe, para que sea más fácil de graficar. Te interesa que los barrios sean las columnas y los diferentes años las filas. Esto es fácil de conseguir:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("H_Poblacion.xls")
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]], axis=1)
df = df.set_index("Barrio").T     # La T es de "Transpose", cambia filas por columnas
df.index=list(range(2008, 2019))  # Reasignar el índice para que sea numérico
```

Ahora el dataframe ya tiene la estructura que necesitamos:

[image: Dataframe]

Basta seleccionar qué columnas queremos ver (podemos especificar varias, en una lista), y pedirle a pandas que haga el `plot()`. No necesitas importar `matplotlib` (pandas lo hace por tí). Si queremos manipular aspectos de la gráfica, como la posición de la leyenda, el etiquetado de los ejes, etc. podemos recoger el resultado devuelto por `DataFrame.plot()`, que será un "axis" matplotlib sobre el que podemos realizar las operaciones necesarias.

Por ejemplo:

```
subset = ["EMBAJADORES", "COMILLAS", "UNIVERSIDAD", "LOS ROSALES", "ARAVACA", ]
ax = df[subset].plot(marker="o")
ax.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Produce:

[image: Plot]
Si prefieres un gráfico de barras, basta usar `kind="bar"` en el plot:

```
ax = df[subset].plot(kind="bar")
ax.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image: De barras]

### Actualización

Respondiendo a un comentario del usuario. Parece que el problema no era tanto cómo crear una función para hacer un gráfico de un DataFrame, sino más bien cómo lograr *mostrar* la gráfica desde idle.

La verdad es que yo siempre he trabajado con Notebooks Jupyter, donde todo es más sencillo porque con sólo importar `pandas` todo está ya configurado para mostar las gráficas en el propio notebook. De no hacerlo así la cosa se complica un poco.

El mecanismo general sería:

- Importar `matplotlib`
- Configurar el *backend* que deseemos usar. El backend es el que al final convierte las gráficas en algo visible, ya sea en una imagen PNG, o en una ventana interactiva en la que se pueda hacer zoom, o en un mini-servidor web que ofrezca una página en la que ver la gráfica, etc. Qué *backends* tienes disponibles depende entre otras cosas del operativo en que estés y de qué otras bibliotecas tengas instaladas. Por ejemplo, si tienes instalado Qt5, puedes usarlo como backend (sería Qt el encargado de crear y mostrar una ventana con la gráfica)
- Importar `matplotlib.pyplot`. El orden es crucial. El *backend* tiene que estar ya configurado (en el paso anterior) antes de importar pyplot.

El resto ya sería fácil. La gráfica puede crearse directamente con pandas como mostré más arriba, y la única diferencia es que hay que invocar explícitamente a `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` para que el *backend* haga visible el resultado.

Un ejemplo mínimo, que usa `TkAgg` como *backend* (que creo que estaría disponible en todos los operativos, aunque sólo lo he probado en Mac), y que usa `pandas` para mostrar una dataframe trivial (no he querido complicarlo más, pero puedes cambiar el dataframe por lo antes explicado), sería así:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  # <---- Especificar el backend

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # <--- Ahora ya podemos importar pyplot

# Crear un dataframe trivial y mostrar la gráfica
df = pd.DataFrame([2,4,1])
df.plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

Eso hace aparecer la gráfica en otra ventana:

[image: idle]

Espero que esto sirva también cuando `idle` es usado desde Arcgis, como es tu caso. Desconozco esa plataforma.

## Actualización 2

Tratando de organizar un poco mejor el código que pones en tu Edicion2, propongo separarlo en dos funciones. Una que lee la excel y la "acondiciona", para dejarla de modo que las columnas sean los barrios y las filas los años; otra que pinte una gráfica de un barrio dado (para lo cual sólo tiene que seleccionar qué columna pintar). Así:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  # <---- Especificar el backend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def leer_excel(filename):
  info_barrios = pd.read_excel(filename)
  info_barrios = info_barrios.drop(info_barrios.columns[[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]], axis=1)
  info_barrios = info_barrios.set_index("Barrio").sort_index().T     # La T es de "Transpose", cambia filas por columnas
  info_barrios.index=list(range(2008, 2019))  # Reasignar el índice para que sea numérico
  return info_barrios

def grafica(data, Barrio):
  plt.plot(data[Barrio])
  plt.show()

df = leer_excel("H_Poblacion.xls")
grafica(df, "ATOCHA")
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente. Usando `"MONCLOA"` en cambio rompe, porque ¡MONCLOA no está entre los datos! Puedes ver qué barrios están si haces un `print list(df.columns)` y lo comprobarás.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, las estructura del df la tengo clara, sé que tengo que trasponer la matriz para que los índices de años aparezcan en abscisas,pero te comento , yo estoy estudiando un máster en tig (tecnologías de la info geográfica) y trabajo con IDLE de Python, (versión 2.7), que es la versión que necesito para escribir scripts para Arcgis, y no sé si es por eso por lo que Pandas no me pinta la gráfica, ya que el IDLE viene integrado en el paquete de Arcgis al instalar ese software y es lo que uso , por eso preguntaba por el método para crear función, llamarla y pintarla con plt.show()

Comment: @Estebancf He actualizado la respuesta. Mira a ver si te sirve. En todo caso la pregunta original no mencionaba nada de esto. Considero que casi se trataría de otra pregunta que sería "Como pintar un gráfico con pandas desde idle"

Comment: gracias por explicarme un poco cómo va, si le puedes echar un ojo al código estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: @Estebancf No debes eliminar la pregunta original y cambiarla por otra, pues eso hace que no tenga sentido la respuesta y que cualquiera que venga luego a leerlo no entienda nada. He revertido el estado de la pregunta a como estaba al principio, y he añadido tu nueva pregunta como una "edición", en vez de sustituir a la primera. Eso sí está permitido. Te respondo en un comentario a la pregunta lo que creo que puede estar mal.

Comment: @Estebancf He hecho una segunda edición a la respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación. Ahora sí me funciona, no es tan complicado ahora que veo la definición de las funciones pero para una persona como yo que acaba de ver código por primera vez se hace un poco cuesta arriba. Te agradezco un montón la explicación, un saludo y de nuevo, gracias